# how to show date in barchart image mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bar-chart

how to echo date in barchart image

i want to echo date here

```
 $xname='For The month of $a to $b'; //X-axis Name
```

how can i do this

please help me to fix this issue thanks

this is barchart code

barchart.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$link=mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password")or 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link);
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}       
$a=$_POST['from'];
$b=$_POST['to'];


 include 'create.php';
    $sql="SELECT division,sum(amount) AS amount FROM $tablename where monthdate BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' GROUP BY division"; // Give Your field Name  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $graphtitle='BarChart ';//Graph Title
    $xname='For The month of $a to $b'; //X-axis Name
    $yname='Values';//y-axis name
    $img_width=1300;//image height
    $img_height=600;//image width 
    $margins=70;
    $ymargin=6;
    $count=mysql_affected_rows();
    $graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
    $graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
    $bar_width=5;
    $total_bars=$count;
    $gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);
    $img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);
    include 'barcolor.php';
    imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,0,0,$bag_color);
    imageline($img,$margins,$img_height-45,$img_width-20,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
    imageline($img,$margins,$ymargin,$margins,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
    $maxvalue="select max(monthdate) as amount from $tablename";//Give your field name for Y axis 
    $max=mysql_query($maxvalue);
    while($inf1= mysql_fetch_array($max)) 
      {
       $ratio=$graph_height/$inf1[0];
      }
    $horizontal_lines=8;
    $horizontal_gap=($img_height+20)/$horizontal_lines;
    for($j=1;$j<=$horizontal_lines;$j++)
    {
            $y=($img_height-48) - $horizontal_gap * $j ;
            //imageline($img,$margins+1,$y,$img_width-20,$y,$hline_color);
            $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $j /$ratio);
            imagestring($img,2,$margins-30,$y-5,$v,$values_color);
    }
    $i=0;
    while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
          $x1=($margins+10) + ($gap+5) + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
          $x2=$x1+$bar_width;
          $y1=($img_height-46)- ceil($inf[1] * $ratio) ; 
          $y2=($img_height-46); 
          imagestring($img,2,$x1+1,$y1-15,$inf[1],$values_color); 
          imagestring($img,2,$x2-23,$img_height-43,$inf[0],$values_color);  
          imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color); // Draw bar
       $i++;   
      }
    imagestring($img,8, ($img_width-$margin)/2, 0, $graphtitle, $txt_color);
    imagestring($img,5, ($img_width-$margin)/2, $img_height-($ymargin+10), $xname, $txt_color);
    imagestringup($img,5,10,($img_height-$ymargin)/2, $yname, $txt_color);
    //header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($img, 'barchart.jpg');
    echo "<div style='border:1px solid #d8d8d8;width:$img_width'><img src='barchart.jpg'></div>";
    ?>
```

here is barcolor.php

```
<?php
$bag_color=imagecolorallocate($img,246,246,246);//Baground color
$xyline_color=imagecolorallocate($img,135,135,135);//XY-axis color
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,172,212,123);//Bar color
$values_color=imagecolorallocate($img,2,2,2);//values color
$txt_color=imagecolorallocate($img,227,113,39);//text color
?>
```

and here is config.php

```
<?php

 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $hostname = "localhost";
        $dbname = "car";
  $tablename = "fuel";

 ?>
```

Comment: Use double quotes like `$xname="For The month of $a to $b";`

Comment: so how can i do this please help me

Comment: thanks..for understand... now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes like `$xname="For The month of $a to $b";`